# how to save pdf file generated by itextpdf without opening it?

Tags: java, itext

am having some data that is coming from database and after that i am able to display that content in pdf format in pop up.But now i want to save that pdf without opening the popup.is it possible?

Any help is appreciated.Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That PDF comes from a database as an input stream. Just save it to a file. [Here's an example](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/InputstreamToFile.shtml).